# Change symbology of one selected feature in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, symbology

I have a layer in ArcGIS Pro which contains over 2000 polyline features.

There are 500 polyline features which have the exact same attributes due to how they were created. If I edit the symbology based on an attribute of the layer it changes them all.

Is there a way to select a certain polyline and specify I want it to be black for example whilst the others in that layer can be red?

Answer (score 1):

To do that I would probably:

1. make a copy of the layer (not a copy of its source data)
2. Change the color of the copied layer
3. Drag the copied layer above the original in the Contents
4. Set a Definition Query on the copied layer so that only the one polyline you are interested in gets displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Since the polyline features all have the same attributes, I would open the attribute table, then select the one you want to make a different color. From there I would click on the layer, then data -> export features. This should create a new layer, and you can just change the symbology of the new layer to be different from the other layer. I also then like to deselect the selected feature from the original layer.